# If $0\leq A \leq B$, is operator $A$ bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space and $A: H \rightarrow H$, $B: H\rightarrow H$ are self-adjoint linear operators such that $0\leq A \leq B$. If $B$ is compact, then it is bounded, but can it be proved that $A $ is bounded? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $\forall x,y\in H\quad \langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,Ay\rangle $ implies $A$ is bounded. E.g by Uniform Boundedness Principle. Details in the accepted answer: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602548/is-every-self-adjoint-operator-bounded)