# Show that $\langle Tx, y \rangle = i\langle x, Ty \rangle$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Can anyone help me prove this?

> Let $T$ be a linear operator in a Hilbert space $H$ so that $\langle Tx, y \rangle = i\langle x, Ty \rangle$ for all $x, y \in H$. Show that $T$ is bounded.

I think I should use the closed graph theorem, but it is not clear to me how to do it. Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is every self-adjoint operator bounded?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602548/is-every-self-adjoint-operator-bounded). This is not totally the same question, however, the proof can be used in a straightforward way

Comment: Thanks. I did a similar argument used in the proof of the Hellinger-Toppeplitz Theorem presented here: https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4230/2016v/thebigtheorems.pdf

Comment: More general fact is true with the same proof as the Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem. If $\langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle x,Sy\rangle$ then both $T$ and $S$ are bounded. In your case $S=-iT.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the observation, @RyszardSzwarc!